# Pandas get column name of max of several column sums in groupby to new column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe on this form:

```
        value1  value2  value3  value4 random string column    group
index1       10      2       3       4                stuff  group 2
index2       5       4       3       2          other stuff  group 1
index3       6       7       8       9          other stuff  group 1
index4       1       2       2       4      yet other stuff  group 2
index5       6       1       8      11          other stuff  group 1
```

This test example can be generated with this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 2, 3, 4, 'stuff', 'group 2'], [5, 4, 3, 2, 'other stuff', 'group 1'], [6, 7, 8, 9, 'other stuff', 'group 1'], [1, 2, 2, 4, 'yet other stuff', 'group 2'], [6, 1, 8, 11, 'other stuff', 'group 1']], columns = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'random string column', 'group'], index=['index1', 'index2', 'index3', 'index4', 'index5'])
```

I want to create a new column called "Group Identifying Column" according to this specification:

1. Groupby the group column
2. Take the sum of each value column
3. Get the column name of the value column with the maximum sum per group

In this example, the expected output would be:

```
        value1  value2  value3  value4 random string column    group Group Identifying Column
index1      10       2       3       4                stuff  group 2                   value1
index2       5       4       3       2          other stuff  group 1                   value4
index3       6       7       8       9          other stuff  group 1                   value4
index4       1       2       2       4      yet other stuff  group 2                   value1
index5       6       1       8      11          other stuff  group 1                   value4
```

I have tried several groupby / apply / transform etc but I can't quite get it to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's extract the columns by group then map:

```
max_cols = (df.filter(like='value')       # choose the value columns, also df.iloc[:, :4]
              .groupby(df['group']).sum() # calculate sum per group
              .idxmax(axis=1)             # find col with max value
           )

df['Column'] = df['group'].map(max_cols)
```

Also `groupby().transform()`:

```
df['Column'] = (df.filter(like='value')
                  .groupby(df['group']).transform('sum')
                  .idxmax(axis=1)
               )
```

Output:

```
        value1  value2  value3  value4 random string column    group  Column
index1      10       2       3       4                stuff  group 2  value1
index2       5       4       3       2          other stuff  group 1  value4
index3       6       7       8       9          other stuff  group 1  value4
index4       1       2       2       4      yet other stuff  group 2  value1
index5       6       1       8      11          other stuff  group 1  value4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one potential solution with `map` and `dictionary`:

```
#creates a dictionary with the maximum sum per group
d = df.groupby('group').sum().idxmax(axis=1).to_dict()

#mapping the dictionary to 'group' column to generated a new column
df['Group Identifying Column'] = df['group'].map(d)
```

Alternatively, you can cutoff the `dictionary` part and simply do:

```
df['Group Identifying Column'] =  df.group.map(df.groupby('group').sum().idxmax(axis=1))
```

**Output**:

```
        value1  value2  ...    group  Group Identifying Column
index1      10       2  ...  group 2                    value1
index2       5       4  ...  group 1                    value4
index3       6       7  ...  group 1                    value4
index4       1       2  ...  group 2                    value1
index5       6       1  ...  group 1                    value4
```